# the default storage drive of Android app developed in eclipse

Tags: android

I am new to Android development.The files of my apps get stored in the C drive.I want to change the default storage to D drive .Please help me.

Comment: do you mean workspace? if workspace then File->Switch Workspace->Other->select path

Comment: app file are stored in your project...which in your case located at `C:` drive..making a workspace in `D:` drive will do your task